# C++ Error with Class pointers as a data member in another class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I keep getting weird C4430 and C2143 errors when I try to compile my code.  My class has data members which point to different classes and the errors are saying that it is expecting a ";" in between the class name and "*".  Here's a summary of my class:

```
#include "CarStack.h"
#include "CarQueue.h"    
#include "CarDeque.h"
#include "base_class.h"

class my_class : public base_class
{
public:
    //Member Functions
private:
    //Other data members
    CarStack* car_stack;
    CarQueue* car_queue;
    CarDeque* car_deque;
};
```

The errors are coming up with those class pointers.  Why would I get errors like this?  Is there something important I'm missing?

Comment: At a guess, you have a circular dependency somewhere. Try replacing the includes with forward declarations (eg replace `#include "CarStack.h"` with `class CarStack;`). Another possibility is that you are missing a bracket or a semicolon somewhere... As it is, your code compiles fine (with some reasonable assumptions about the contents of the `#include` files) -- see http://liveworkspace.org/code/a3e19ce00a5f1db746a4939b0537ef22. Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: Are the classes you include part of a different namespace than the one, in which `my_class` resides?

Comment: When posting a question about compilation or linker errors, please include the _complete_ and _unedited_ error messages. Also indicate in the source which line the error(s) is about.

Comment: C4430 is missing type-specifier.  It's my guess the actual problem with your code is either in the included header files or in the rest of the class definition.  I can't see anything wrong with this code snippet on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

if base class or any of the car classes call one of the ones in this list, you'll get cyclic dependencies.  There are a lot of solutions for this.

The solution I find the best: copy paste from my recent opengl project "Include.h" contains:

```
#ifndef _INCLUDE_H
#define _INCLUDE_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "gl/gl.h"
#incldue "gl/glu.h"

#include "Most Derived Classes"
#include "Most Derived Classes"

#endif
```

then, just use `#include "Include.h"` at the start of your project's main driver file.  Then, only include the base header of your derived classes.

I think that is a much better solution a bunch of forward declarations, IMO.